# How do I create a range when making an if statement

Tags: python, string, limit

I'm new to python. I need help with this code:

```py
price = 1000000
credit = int(input("What is your credit score? "))
if credit >= 670:
    print("Since you have a high credit score, you will have to only put down 10% for your new home! ")
    new_price = price/10
    print(f"The price you will have to pay is ${new_price}!")
elif credit <= 670:
    print("Due to your low credit score, you will have to put down 20% for your new home.")
    new_price = price/5
    print(f"The price you will have to pay is ${new_price}!")
elif credit <= 0:
    print("Sorry, that is not a valid credit score!")
elif credit >= 850:
    print("Sorry, that is not a valid credit score!")
else:
    print("Sorry, but you haven't typed in a number! Run the program to try again.")
print("Have a great day!")
```

So, I tried running the code with a really high number, thinking it will result in "Sorry that is not a valid credit score", but then I realized that there isn't a limit I put here:

```py
if credit >= 670:
    print("Since you have a high credit score, you will have to only put down 10% for your new home! ")
    new_price = price/10
    print(f"The price you will have to pay is ${new_price}!")
```

So, it thinks that any score 670 or higher is a high credit score. Is there a code, or some way I can make it so that a high credit score is at least 670, and at max 850?

Comment: Order matters. If `credit >= 670` was already matched, then it's not looking at any `elif` clauses, so it'll never see `credit >= 850`.

Comment: Put your conditions in a more sensible order.

Comment: There's no way for your `else` to be reached, since`int(input(...))` will raise an exception if something other than an integer is entered.

Comment: There exist programming languages where the developer just declares a bunch of rules, and the language figures out the right order to evaluate things in to efficiently evaluate all inputs against those rules; but Python is not one of them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Interesting! I don't believe I've worked with such a language.

Comment: @FredLarson, for a classic example, see http://www.clipsrules.net/AboutCLIPS.html or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog; among more modern examples, one of my coworkers in the lead developer of [Naga](https://github.com/threatgrid/naga); [core.logic](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic) is also noteworthy. I'm trying to remember another language with similar inspiration specialized for finding patterns in real-time data streams, but it's escaping me right now.

Comment: @FredLarson, ...ahh; I was thinking about [Esper](http://www.espertech.com/esper/) (which I once wrote a Clojure wrapper around, maybe about a decade ago; alas, internal to a former employer and afaik never released).

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It worked! by putting the two bottom "elifs" at the top, I was able to make the program check for validation that the number that the user put in, is a credit score!

Answer (score 0):

You have different conditions with an equal sign to 670,you should be exclusive with ur if else elif statememts, as they are actually mutually exclusive, like so:

`if credit < 670:`

`elif 670 <= credit <= 850:`

`else:`

Then, if you want all conditional statements to be checked, use several `if` statements. if you use `if, elif` and `else`, as soon as one case matches the others won't be checked. When using only `if` all statements are checked, no matter if one matched before.

Comment: Yeh sorry I meant conditions...

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense.